# Unable to load resource from jar on latest JVM versions

Tags: java, jar, version

Loading resource files from a jar file (a png to build an ImageIcon) worked well for 18 years. Still works with Hotspot java version "1.8.0_333". Running with Hotspot java version "18.0.1.1" fails to load the resource... All this with the same jar file, that I did check and contains the resource file.

```
String fileName = "/images/logo.png";
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon();

byte[] imageBytes = null;
InputStream in = image.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
if (in == null) {
  System.out.println("could not find " + fileName);
}
```

Above - code snippet. in is effectively null when using 18.0.1.1... Anyone has seen difference in processing getResourceAsStream from one version to the other ?

Comment: Does it work with JDK 9? If not, the issue is probably because of java's internal modularization introduced with 9. Instead of `image.getClass()`, try your own type as the basis for the resource.

Comment: Did not try with JDK 9. But your explanation made sense - Of course. I used my own type (coming from same jar file as resource file) and BINGO ! it works like a charm. Thanks akarnokd for this super fast, super clear resolution !

Comment: @JackD Now you can draft, post, and accept an Answer to your own Question, for posterity.

Comment: Don’t call `getResourceAsStream` on just any class, especially not a Java SE class.  You should be using *your own class* for that call.  For instance, `MyApplication.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName)`